# Email Send Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, error

I just "sent" an email but the status of the activity is cancel.
It has an ampscript  that seems to be correct.

Where can I check the error or the reason of the cancelation?

The ampscript is:

```
%%[ 

VAR @nombre, @balance, @saldo 
SET @nombre = AttributeValue('nombre') 
SET @balance = AttributeValue('balance_cuenta') 
SET @saldo = 0.01) 

]%%
```

The body of the email has:

```
Tienes %%balance_cuenta%% puntos en tu cuenta, equivalentes a 
$%%=Multiply(@balance,@saldo)=%% MXN que puedes utilizar en tu compra.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got a stray paren on the `SET @saldo = 0.01` line.

I'd add some conditionals and do the math in the same block:

```
%%[ 

var @nombre, @balance, @saldo, @ext, @balance_output
set @nombre = AttributeValue('nombre') 
set @balance = AttributeValue('balance_cuenta') 
set @saldo = 0.01
set @ext = "$0.00"
set @balance_output = "$0.00"

if not empty(@balance) then
  set @ext = multiply(@balance, @saldo)
  set @ext = formatCurrency(@ext,"en-US")
  set @balance_output = formatCurrency(@balance,"en-US")
endif

]%%

Tienes %%=v(@balance_output)=%% puntos en tu cuenta, equivalentes 
a %%=v(@ext)=%% MXN que puedes utilizar en tu compra.
```

**Reference**

- [**FormatCurrency()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/formatcurrency)